Show that: $(\frac{MN}{MA})^2+ (\frac{MP}{MB})^2+ (\frac{MQ}{MC})^2+ (\frac{MR}{MD})^2 \geq \frac{4 }{9}$
The problem
Let $M$ be a point inside the tetrahedron $ABCD$. We denote by $N,P,Q,R$ the intersections of the lines $AM,BM,MC,DM$ with the planes $(BCD),(ACD),(ABD)$, respectively $(ABC)$. Show that:
$(\frac{MN}{MA})^2+ (\frac{MP}{MB})^2+ (\frac{MQ}{MC})^2+ (\frac{MR}{MD})^2 \geq \frac{4 }{9}$
my idea
drawing

The fact that all of these factions are squared up makes me think of using AM-GM inequality to get to a better form.
Also, the fact that we have fractions got me drawing some lines parallel with the planes $(BCD),(ACD),(ABD)$, respectively $(ABC)$ from point M and applying the theorem of Thales we get another form of the sum  $(\frac{MN}{MA})^2+ (\frac{MP}{MB})^2+ (\frac{MQ}{MC})^2+ (\frac{MR}{MD})^2$
The thing is that I don't know what to do from there. Is there any way of solving these without vectors, because i didnt learn about them yett...
I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Just an idea: Can we start by an affine transformation? Would it preserve ratios, and can it map the points to certain points which make certain computations easier?

@Euclid I dont understand what are you saying. Yes, I think that we should find other ratios that help us more...the ones that are given doesn't help us...

For a tetrahedron $WXYZ$, denote its volume by $[WXYZ]$.
We have $\dfrac{[MBCD]}{[ABCD]} = \dfrac{|MN|}{|AN|}$. This is because the ratio of these volumes is equal to the ratio of the altitudes from points $M$ and $A$ to plane $BCD$ (due to base $\triangle BCD$ being common), and the ratio of these altitudes is equal to $\dfrac{|MN|}{|AN|}$ by similar triangles.
Similarly, we have $\dfrac{[MACD]}{[ABCD]} = \dfrac{|MP|}{|BP|}$, and $\dfrac{[MABD]}{[ABCD]} = \dfrac{|MQ|}{|CQ|}$, and $\dfrac{[MABC]}{[ABCD]} = \dfrac{|MR|}{|DR|}$.
Denote $\dfrac{|MN|}{|AN|} = a$ , $\dfrac{|MP|}{|BP|} = b$, $\dfrac{|MQ|}{|CQ|} = c$, $\dfrac{|MR|}{|DR|} = d$. We see that
$\begin{align}
1 &= \dfrac{[ABCD]}{[ABCD]} \\
&= \dfrac{ [MBCD] + [MACD] + [MABD] + [MABC] }{[ABCD]} \\
&= \dfrac{|MN|}{|AN|} + \dfrac{|MP|}{|BP|} + \dfrac{|MQ|}{|CQ|} + \dfrac{|MR|}{|DR|} \\
&= a + b + c + d.
\end{align}$
Now let us express the ratios $\dfrac{|MN|}{|MA|}, \dfrac{|MP|}{|MB|}, \dfrac{|MQ|}{|MC|}, \dfrac{|MR|}{|MD|}$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$.
$\begin{align}
\dfrac{|MN|}{|MA|} &= \dfrac{|MN|}{|AN|-|MN|} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{ \frac{|AN|-|MN|}{|MN|} } \\
&= \dfrac{1}{ \frac{|AN|}{|MN|} - 1 } \\
&= \dfrac{1}{ \frac{1}{a} - 1 } \\
&= \dfrac{a}{1-a}.
\end{align}$
Similarly, $\dfrac{|MP|}{|MB|} = \dfrac{b}{1-b}$ , $\dfrac{|MQ|}{|MC|} = \dfrac{c}{1-c}$, and $\dfrac{|MR|}{|MD|} = \dfrac{d}{1-d}$.
Therefore, what we want to prove is $\left( \dfrac{a}{1-a} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{b}{1-b} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{c}{1-c} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{d}{1-d} \right)^2 \ge \dfrac 4 9$ subject to $a+b+c+d = 1$ and $a,b,c,d > 0$. Below is one possible way of doing this (among many others).
Using QM-AM inequality, or simply by Cauchy-Schwarz, we get $$\left( \dfrac{a}{1-a} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{b}{1-b} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{c}{1-c} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{d}{1-d} \right)^2 \ge \dfrac14 \left( \dfrac{a}{1-a} + \dfrac{b}{1-b} + \dfrac{c}{1-c} + \dfrac{d}{1-d} \right)^2 ,$$ so it is enough to lower-bound the quantity $\dfrac{a}{1-a} + \dfrac{b}{1-b} + \dfrac{c}{1-c} + \dfrac{d}{1-d}$.
$\begin{align}
\dfrac{a}{1-a} + \dfrac{b}{1-b} + \dfrac{c}{1-c} + \dfrac{d}{1-d} &= \dfrac{a}{b+c+d} + \dfrac{b}{a+c+d} + \dfrac{c}{a+b+d} + \dfrac{d}{a+b+c} \\
&= \dfrac{a^2}{ab+ac+ad} + \dfrac{b^2}{ba+bc+bd} + \dfrac{c^2}{ca+cb+cd} + \dfrac{d^2}{da+db+dc} \\
&\ge \dfrac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)} \qquad \text{by Cauchy-Schwarz} \\
&\ge \dfrac43 \qquad \text{by adding up } (a-b)^2 \ge 0 \text{ and others}.
\end{align}$
This implies $\left( \dfrac{a}{1-a} + \dfrac{b}{1-b} + \dfrac{c}{1-c} + \dfrac{d}{1-d} \right)^2 \ge \dfrac{16}{9}$, and therefore
$\begin{align}
\left( \dfrac{|MN|}{|MA|} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{|MP|}{|MB|} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{|MQ|}{|MC|} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{|MR|}{|MD|} \right)^2 &= \left( \dfrac{a}{1-a} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{b}{1-b} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{c}{1-c} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{d}{1-d} \right)^2 \\
&\ge \dfrac14 \left( \dfrac{a}{1-a} + \dfrac{b}{1-b} + \dfrac{c}{1-c} + \dfrac{d}{1-d} \right)^2 \\
&\ge \dfrac14 \cdot \dfrac{16}{9} \\
&= \dfrac49
\end{align}$
as desired. $\blacksquare$

Thank you so much for your answer! May I ask how you got to the fact that $$ \frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)}
\geq \frac{4}{3} $$? Thanks again!

First note the identity $$(a+b+c+d)^2 = (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) + 2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd).$$ The inequality of interest is equivalent to $$3(a+b+c+d)^2 \ge 8(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$$ which, due to the mentioned identity, is equivalent to $$3(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) \ge 2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd),$$ which is nothing but $$(a-b)^2 + (a-c)^2 + (a-d)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (b-d)^2 + (c-d)^2 \ge 0,$$ which is clearly true.

Let $\displaystyle \overrightarrow{BM}=\overrightarrow{BE}+\overrightarrow{BF}+\overrightarrow{BG}$, where $\overrightarrow{BE}=x\overrightarrow{BA}$, $\overrightarrow{BF}=y\overrightarrow{BC}$, $\overrightarrow{BG}=z\overrightarrow{BD}$ with $x,y,z\in [0,1]$ and $x+y+z\leq 1$. Then it becomes straightforward that $\displaystyle \frac{MN}{MA}=\frac{BE}{EA}=\frac{x}{1-x}$, $\displaystyle \frac{MQ}{MC}=\frac{BF}{CF}=\frac{y}{1-y}$, $\displaystyle \frac{MR}{MD}=\frac{BG}{GD}=\frac{z}{1-z}$. To get $\displaystyle \frac{MP}{MB}$ is a little harder, but I can tell you a theorem that for any point $H$ ON the plane $ACD$, if you decompose $\displaystyle \overrightarrow{BH}$ into $x'\overrightarrow{BA}+y'\overrightarrow{BC}+z'\overrightarrow{BD}$, there is always $x'+y'+z'=1$. With this theorem, just let $\overrightarrow{BP}=k\overrightarrow{BM}=k(x\overrightarrow{BA}+y\overrightarrow{BC}+z\overrightarrow{BD})$, where $k\geq 1$, and then we have $k(x+y+z)=1$. Therefore $\displaystyle \frac{MP}{BM}=\frac{BP-BM}{BM}=k-1=\frac{1-x-y-z}{x+y+z}$.

Then we have \begin{aligned} &\bigg(\frac{MN}{MA}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{MP}{MB}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{MQ}{MC}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{MR}{MD}\bigg)^2\\=&\bigg(\frac{x}{1-x}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{y}{1-y}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{z}{1-z}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{1-x-y-z}{x+y+z}\bigg)^2\\\geq&\frac{1}{4}\bigg(\frac{x}{1-x}+\frac{y}{1-y}+\frac{z}{1-z}+\frac{1-x-y-z}{x+y+z}\bigg)^2.\end{aligned}
Then let's consider this function $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$, with $\displaystyle f(x)'=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$ increasing on $[0,1]$. Then by Jensen's inequality, we have \begin{aligned} &\frac{x}{1-x}+\frac{y}{1-y}+\frac{z}{1-z}+\frac{1-x-y-z}{x+y+z}\\\geq&4f\bigg(\frac{1}{4}(x+y+z+1-x-y-z)\bigg)\\=&4f\bigg(\frac{1}{4}\bigg)=\frac{4}{3},\end{aligned} which implies
$\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}\bigg(\frac{x}{1-x}+\frac{y}{1-y}+\frac{z}{1-z}+\frac{1-x-y-z}{x+y+z}\bigg)^2\geq\frac{1}{4}\bigg(\frac{4}{3}\bigg)^2=\frac{4}{9}.$

Thanks for your answer! Sorry for asking, but there is any way to explain this problem without vectors, cause I didn't learned about them yet? Thanks again!

It may be not difficult to prove $\displaystyle \frac{MN}{MA}=\frac{BE}{EA}=\frac{x}{1-x}$, $\displaystyle \frac{MQ}{MC}=\frac{BF}{CF}=\frac{y}{1-y}$, $\displaystyle \frac{MR}{MD}=\frac{BG}{GD}=\frac{z}{1-z}$ without vectors. This is quite straightforward I think. But to prove $\displaystyle \frac{MP}{MB}=\frac{1-x-y-z}{x+y+z}$, it may be a little bit complicated without using vectors. You can google the proof for that theorem, and I guess there will be some explanations without using vectors, which will basically construct some parallel auxiliary lines. You can skip this part.

Affine transformation
Euclid has already mentioned that you can make affine transformations to move the points $A,B,C,D$ to arbitrary positions. Let me explain what that means since you're not familiar with the concept:
Let's say you keep the plane $BCD$ and point $N$ in place, but move the point $A$ while moving the point $M$ so that it stays on the $AN$ line with the ratio $MN:MA$ unchanged. Doing this will also leave the other ratios, $MP:MB$ etc, unchanged. You can then move points $B$, $C$, and $D$ in the same manner.
Since all the ratios are unchanged, the sum is also unchanged.
Thus, you can move the corners to make $ABCD$ a regular tetrahedron, eg one with height 1 from each corner to opposing side.
Convexity
Let's assume that we keep the tetrahedron $ABCD$ fixed, while the point $M$ can vary.
Let $h_A$ denote the height from $A$ to $BCD$, and $m_A$ denote the height from $M$ to $BCD$. Then $MN:MA=\frac{m_A}{h_A-m_A}$. Since $h_A$ is constant, we can view this as a function in $m_A$. We can then do the same for the other corners.
Note that the expression $\left(\frac{m}{h-m}\right)^2$ is convex in $m$ for $0\le m<h$: ie it curves upwards. In fact, it is strictly convex: ie has no linear segments.
Now, let $M=(x,y,z)$. The height $m_A$ is a linear expression in the coordinates, ie $m_A=a_0+a_xx+a_yy+a_zz$ for some constants $a_0,a_x,a_y,a_z$ that depend on the points $A,B,C,D$. This makes
$$
\left(\frac{MN}{MA}\right)^2
= \left(\frac{m_A}{h_A-m_A}\right)^2
= \left(\frac{a_0+a_xx+a_yy+a_zz}{h_A-(a_0+a_xx+a_yy+a_zz)}\right)^2
$$
a convex function in the coordinates $x,y,z$.
Again, the same applies to the other corners. The sum
$$
S(x,y,z)=
\left(\frac{MN}{MA}\right)^2
+\left(\frac{MP}{MB}\right)^2
+\left(\frac{MQ}{MC}\right)^2
+\left(\frac{MR}{MD}\right)^2
$$
is now a sum of four convex functions, and so is itself convex. In fact, it is strictly convex since each of the four terms is strictly convex in the corresponding heights.
Since $S(x,y,z)$ is strictly convex, it must have a unique minimum.
Finding the minimum
First, we use an affine transformation to make the tetrahedron regular with all heights equal to 1. Place $M$ in the unique minimum of the sum $S$.
However, if we rotate the tetrahedron (and the point $M$ along with it) so as to permute the corners, we must end up with the same function $S(x,y,z)$, which must have the same unique minimum. So the minimum $M$ must be left in place, meaning it has to be the center point of the regular tetrahedron.
When $M$ is in the center of the regular tetrahedron, the ratios $MN:MA$ etc are all $1/3$, and so the sum $S=4/9$. Since this is the minimum, we must have $S\ge4/9$ for all points $M$ inside the tetrahedron.
And then a somewhat simpler approach...
After finishing, I realised that the following sum
$$
\frac{MN}{AN}+\frac{MP}{BP}+\frac{MQ}{CQ}+\frac{MR}{DR}
= \frac{m_A}{h_A}+\frac{m_B}{h_B}+\frac{m_C}{h_C}+\frac{m_D}{h_D}
= 1.
$$
If we let $a,b,c,d$ denote the four ratios, we have $a+b+c+d=1$ and need to prove that $f(a)+f(b)+f(c)+f(d)\ge\frac{4}{9}$ when $f(t)=\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)^2$, which again can be done using the convexity argument above.
But I guess there may be even simpler ways to prove the inequality using this identity.

This is actually pretty simple if we use this question I specifically created for this solution. Denoting the four ratios $a,b,c,d$ respectively, the linked solution tells us:
$$\sum ab + 2\sum abc + 3abcd = 1$$
where again I use the $\sum $ for cyclic summation. Now you just need to prove:
$$x^2 :=\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{4}\geq\dfrac{ab+bc+cd+da +ac+bd}{6}$$
and
which is nothing but term-wise AM-GM. That $abcd\leq x^4$ is also a trivial AM-GM. For the middle term:
$$\sum abc = ab(c+d)+cd(a+b)\leq\dfrac{(a+b)(c+d)}{4}(a+b+c+d)\leq\dfrac{(a+b+c+d)^3}{16}\leq$$
$$\leq 4x^3$$
by power-mean inequality. Therefore, you get:
$$6x^2+8x^3+3x^4\geq 1\implies (x+1)^3(3x-1)\implies x\geq \frac 13$$
This obviously implies
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=4x^2\geq\frac 49.$$
Note that a credit must be given to @Euclid for answering my linked question.
